# Cordapp Web Application

Tags: html, spring-boot, corda

Is there any documentation on how to build web application with CORDA as underlying technology. Need to be able to create a web application (html and js) to visualize the states and transactions of each node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches:

- Using SpringBoot to create a webserver. You can find a template [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/spring-webserver), and a detailed example implementation [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp).
- Using Braid server and Open API generator. You can find an example that uses ReactJS [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/iou-reactfrontend-Braid).
- I wrote about Braid server in [this article](https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-braid-server-and-openapi-generator-for-corda-flows-api-s-d24179ccb27c).
- Samples are also written in Kotlin. Here's [the deprecated repo](https://github.com/corda/samples) that was split into Java samples, and [Kotlin samples](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need a little bit more clarification as I am new to both Springboot and Corda. Should the RPC API calls go here https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Basic/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/controllers/CustomController.java and the result of API calls be presented through request paths in the front end?

Comment: Have a look at [the clients module](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/clients) of the obligations CorDapp. You will see several files.

Comment: `Server.java` is the SpringBoot app, which is the webserver.

Comment: `NodeRPCConnection.java` is the RPC connection that is used by the webserver to connect to the node, and used by the controller to make calls to the node.

Comment: `MainController.java` is the controller class, this is where you define your API's; you will see many examples on how to call a flow or query the vault.

Comment: Inside the `build.gradle` file of the `clients` module, you will see multiple tasks to start webservers (for instance `runPartyAServer`). So after starting the `PartyA` node, you can start its webserver with `./gradlew runPartyAServer`.

Comment: I suggest that you go through the obligations CorDapp in detail, have a look at its `README.md` file to understand how to run it. Then look at the code (especially the `clients` module).

Comment: I can keep explaining things forever here, but unless you do your part and go through the code in detail, you won't learn.

Answer (score 0):

You will write the web application as you would normally do and when it is necessary to communicate with the node you do it via RPC: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/clientrpc.html.

There is an example here: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver